# Restriction in anonymous classes

Tags: java, anonymous-class

Can we define a method in anonymous class other than a method present in a super class?if yes how is it possible and how can we access it
like for example

```
abstract class a
{
  public void method()
  {
  }
}
class b
{
  public static void main(String arr[])
  {
    a x=new a()
    {
     public void y()
     {
     }
    };
  }
}
```

how can we access `y()` method?

Answer (score 2):

> Can we define a method in anonymous class other than a method present in a super class?

Yes. In fact you just did it in your example.

> how can we access y() method??

Unfortunately you can't access that method on `x` reference, for obvious reasons. Compiler cannot find `y()` method declaration class `A`. The only way to access that method directly on the anonymous class instance creation expression like this:

```
new A() {
    public void y()
    {
    } 
}.y();
```

But that is hardly of any use.

Or you can call it from another method of class `A`, which you override it in anonymous inner class.

```
class A {
    public void demo() {        
    }
}

A obj = new A() {
        public void demo() {
            demo2();
        }

        public void demo2() {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    };

    obj.demo();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define this type of method, but you only can access it form other methods in the same abstract class:

```
abstract class a
{
  public void method()
  {
  }
}
class b
{
  public static void main(String arr[])
  {
    a x=new a()
    {
     public void y()
     {
     }
     public void method() {
        // call y()
        y();
    };
  }
}
```